# Display multiple related lists on a single page with paging

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, custom-list

I need to display multiple SharePoint custom lists in a single page. Let me explain the requirement with following example:

```
 List 1: User List
 Columns:
   1. Name
   2. Age
   3. Gender
   4. DOB

 List 2: Address List
 Columns:
    1. UserName(reference to User list)
    2. Address1
    3. Address2
    4. City

List 3: Company List
Columns:
   1. UserName(reference to User list)
   2. Company Name
```

Now I need to show all these lists in a single page with paging.

Let's say we have 10 records in each list and have page size of 3.

Now total pages will be 4 (3+3+3+1).

- On page index 1, lists should display 3 records each (List 1 will have paging and other two lists will have related records).
- On page index 2, each list will still display 3 records (Records in List 1 will change and List 2 & 3 will show new records related to current values in List 1).

I am doing this in browser only. I have SharePoint Office 365 license so I can not do any coding to achieve this.

Comment: This can be achieved via SharePoint hosted app. Are you open to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use ContentQuery Webpart for this?

This webpart selected data from Lists and Display them in an form you choose.

the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650512.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396